# Problema al redireccionar desde Mercado Pago con React, Redux y NodeJS App

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mercadopago, redux

Estoy creando una aplicacion web con react (utilizando redux) y nodejs, tengo como base de datos MongoDB. Actualmente estoy notando un problema bastante curioso.

Al realizar una compra ejemplo (la pagina esta a modo prueba aun), eligiendo mercadopago como metodo de pago. Al volver desde el checkout de mercadopago a la pagina, en un primer momento es como que se olvidaran todos los datos almacenados en REDUX. Se pierde el nombre del usuario, los datos de la orden, etc. Como si nunca se hubiera iniciado sesion.

Curiosamente esto sucede solo la primera vez que se realiza el proceso. Ya que si una vez que sucede, se vuelve a ingresar a la pagina y se repite el proceso este ya funciona bien.

La verdad que el problema me tiene mareado al no tener idea que puede ser. Agradeceria que me brinden pistas sobre lo q puede llegar a ser.

La web en cuestion es : https://aldonza.herokuapp.com/
por si quieren probarlo por su cuenta.

Gracias desde ya!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow! Puedes publicar tu código? El parte de redux por ejemplo. Ya que asi es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta carece de un [mcve]. Para poder ayudarte debemos al menos poder reproducir el problema. No necesita subir todo tu programa, sólo lo mínimo para poder ver donde se haya el problema. Tal como está tu pregunta, es como intentar dar en el blanco con los ojos tapados. Saludos